# Why Can't I Use TEntity?

Tags: entity-framework

It seems like the most simplistic things are hard to figure out sometimes...
Many code references have the type TEntity used for generic handling of entities in an entity data model. I tried to use it in my code and get: "Unknown type 'TEntity'" what gives??? Why do I get "Unknown type"? Is this only available in .net 4.0?

BTW: Using .net 3.5.

I'm trying to use code from [this book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx):

```
public TEntity ExecuteFirstorDefault<TEntity>(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery)
  {
    try
    {
      return objectQuery.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (EntitySqlException ex)
    {
      throw ex; //TODO: Replace with handling code
      //additional exceptions as described in Chapter 18
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, it's like asking "I see `List<T>` popping a lot, what is that `T`?".

Comment: The reason I was getting "Unknown type" is because after defining the Method name I forgot to add <TEntity>. I had:

    `Public TEntity Blah(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery) {}`

Instead of:

    `Public TEntity Blah<TEntity>(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery) {}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TEntity`  is a [generic type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx), not a concrete type.

---

> I guess my question is why I can't use it, why do I get Unknown type.

Because it's **not a concrete type.**

Say you have a generic list implementation, declared as `List<T>`. `T` is a **type parameter**, which means that it does not represent a specific type. As the programmer, you have to instruct the compiler to use a specific type to use, rather than the generic type `T`, by providing a **type argument.** You could create a list of integers like so:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();
```

In this example, the type argument is `int`. All the generic methods (or properties) of `List` that accept or return a `T` will instead use `int`.

#### Further reading

- [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: I guess my question is why I can't use it, why do I get Unknown type. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See my edit. This is a matter of generics, which is a language feature of C#. It has nothing specifically to do with EF. Does that clarify things?

Comment: I'm trying to use code from this book: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx)
`public TEntity ExecuteFirstorDefault<TEntity>(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery)
  {
    try
    {
      return objectQuery.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (EntitySqlException ex)
    {
      throw ex; //TODO: Replace with handling code
      //additional exceptions as described in Chapter 18
    }
  }`

Comment: That's a generic method. If you don't have a good handle on C# generics, you should take a step back from EF, and wrap your head around generics.

Comment: All i want to know is if I'm missing a reference or using statement? I pasted that exact code into my class and get compile errors. "Unknown type". I understand that it's not a concrete type and that it's using generics but why can she use it in the book but I can't??

Comment: The reason I was getting "Unknown type" is because after defining the Method name I forgot to add <TEntity>. I had:

    Public TEntity Blah(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery) {}

Instead of:

    Public TEntity Blah<TEntity>(ObjectQuery<TEntity> objectQuery) {}

Comment: I gave you the answer anyways since the reason I had trouble is because of an oversight of Generics, which you suggested.